# I need to create a SQL query that sets the date_listed to -245 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I can update the date_listed to a particular date I need

```
UPDATE properties
SET date_listed = '2015-06-15 10:28:39.250'
WHERE Users_id = 838598
and status = 'inactive'
```

But I want it to automatically update to -245 days without me having to figure out the date every time

Comment: Please specify what SQL flavor you are using (MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Next time put that also as a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you're looking for (*if you're using **SQL Server***):

```
UPDATE properties
SET date_listed = DATEADD(DAY, -245, GETDATE())
WHERE Users_id = 838598
AND status = 'inactive'
```

It seems you're updating it with 245 days before the current date.

Otherwise, if you want to update the value to 245 days before the date_listed, just use this:

```
UPDATE properties
SET date_listed = DATEADD(DAY, -245, date_listed)
WHERE Users_id = 838598
AND status = 'inactive'
```

**For Oracle**, update to 245 days before current date:

```
UPDATE properties
SET date_listed = systimestamp - 245
WHERE Users_id = 838598
AND status = 'inactive'
```

or update to 245 days before the date in date_listed:

```
UPDATE properties
SET date_listed = date_listed - 245
WHERE Users_id = 838598
AND status = 'inactive'
```

Comment: @gabb_mutt You're welcome. Please don't forget to upvote / mark the answer as correct on all correct and helpful answers here on StackOverflow.